# flutter exchange data between two viewmodels

Tags: design-patterns, flutter, dart, widget, viewmodel

I've got two Widgets which should communicate with each other. Both have a ViewModel connected.

The Calendar Widget:

```
BaseWidget<CalendarViewModel>(
    model: CalendarViewModel(),
    builder: (context, calendarModel, child) => ...
        Consumer<CalendarViewModel>(
            builder: (context, model, child) {
                model.generateEvents(mainModel.activities);

                return calendar(...);
            },
        ),
```

```
class CalendarViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {

}
```

The Data Widget:

```
BaseWidget<MonthDataViewModel>(
    model: MonthDataViewModel(
        visibleMonth: mainModel.displayedMonth,
    ),
    builder: (context, monthDataModel, child) => 
        Text('${DateFormat('MMMM').format(monthDataModel.visibleMonth)}',),

    ),
),
```

```
class MonthDataViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  DateTime _visibleMonth;

  MonthDataViewModel({
    @required DateTime visibleMonth,
  }) {
    _visibleMonth = visibleMonth;
  }

  DateTime get visibleMonth => _visibleMonth;
  set visibleMonth(DateTime month) => {
        _visibleMonth = month,
        notifyListeners(),
      };
}
```

So now there is a Function inside the calendar widget which fires, when the visible month has changed. I then want to change the text inside the MonthDataWidget based on the month name. The Problem here is, that I don't know how to connect the two viewmodels (or do i exchange data via the widgets itself?) without breaking the pattern

I also use the provider pattern if this could help here, but I actually don't inject any Viewmodel

Comment: Is BaseWidget wrapped inside a Consumer too?

Comment: Actually not, but for sure CalendarViewModel is wrapped inside a BaseWidget.. I updated the source to clearify

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to reference the view model as singleton using get_it to not instantiate the view model each time the view is built. This way the view models can reference and update each other to then notify their respective views.